# Buttons appearing blank on some pages of Xamarin UWP app

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am working on a Xamarin application, I have different pages, and when launching the UWP app, on some of the pages, buttons are of the same color as the page itself (see image 1). They still work properly and are clickable, but you have to point them with the cursor for them to appear in their usual color (see image 2).

I precise that I haven't set any color property, neither for the page or the button, so I don't understand this behavior.

[image: The buttons Register and Cancel are white on this page instead of grey]

[image]

Here is the XAML code of my page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IrisApp.Core.Views"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             Title="Binding {Title}"
             x:Class="IrisApp.Core.Views.RegistrationPage" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label Text="User Name"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding UserName}" Placeholder="User Name" />

            <Label Text="Password"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Password" />

            <Label Text="Email"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email Address" />

            <Picker Title="Select your favorite shop">
                ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableShops}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding FavoriteShop}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding UseNearestShop, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}"
            </Picker>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Always use nearest shop"/>
                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding UseNearestShop}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Text="Register" Command="{Binding FinalizeRegistrationCommand}" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelRegistrationCommand}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>`enter code here`
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: As i understand you are talking about button behavior, It is default template of button if you place cursor on button or click it changes color but you can edit it using blend, or manually edit button default style by editing it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: ShubhamSahu is right here. You can check into "PointOver" VisualState in details.By the way,@ShubhamSahu you can create an answer out.

Comment: I know that I can manually edit the button default style, but what surprises me here, is that I have different content pages on my app, each containing some buttons, and an some of the content page the button appear grey and on some of them, it appears blank, like the page. So I don't understand why the behavior is different for similar content...

Comment: @Toto Can you be specific about "some" content page here?Are they on the same project? Will they run on the same OS? Have you set themeresource at app level? I suspect it is related to button's default brush, which uses theme brush like SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush. There are many possible reasons for this brush changes, like OS version, SDK version or changes by yourself. We need some more details to help you understand it.